How to extract the data-v-xxx by using Selenium in Python?
Since I would like to look through the text inside each class='num' whether larger than 0.
If test is pass, then I need to get the text inside of venuen-name. I observe that, the data-v is the same. So my approah is get the same data-v-<hash value> to lookup the venuen-name. I tried different way to extract, but it still can't. Any suggestion?
Here is the DOM
<div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-row chooseTime" data-v-012d0593="">
    <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-col el-col-5 el-col-xs-0">
        <img data-v-174fb000="" data-v-3122d63c=""
            src="https://lcsd-smartplay.oss-cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/pic/default_facility.jpeg" alt="smartplay"
            class="venuen-img">
    </div>
    <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-col el-col-9 el-col-xs-24">
        <h3 data-v-3122d63c="" class="venuen-name">foo</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-col el-col-10 el-col-xs-24">
        <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-row">
            <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="site el-col el-col-24">boo</div>
            <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-col el-col-24 el-col-xs-24" style="padding: 2px 0px;">
                <div data-v-752ea580="" data-v-3122d63c="" class="facilities-date-list-box">
                    <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" data-v-752ea580="">
                        <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" class="smart-play-mobile">

                        </div><!----><!----><!---->
                        <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" class="smart-play-mobile-tablet">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-hidden scroll-wrap-223-308">
                        <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-scroll scroll-223-308">
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">yyy</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">xxx</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">zzz</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">qqq</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">qqq</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" data-v-752ea580="">
                        <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" class="smart-play-mobile"></div><!----><!----><!---->
                        <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" class="smart-play-mobile-tablet"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


for element in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'num'):
        if int(element.text) == 1:
            vue_hash = element.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor::div[contains(@data-v-,'')]").text


Hi, Can you please double check your provided DOM? - all the elements with @class="num" have the value 0? - can you please confirm which text you're expecting? I've read it a few times and i'm assmming it's the text you changed to "foo"?

whats the site/url?

@RichEdwards Hello, the DOM is correct. @class="num" is showing the avaliable of venue of different time slot. if it is 0, it means no venue avaliable of particular time slot. However, you will see 0 in serveral lines.

@chitown88 I am not sure whether I can share the url to u

theres no nodes where the num is > 0. So not sure what you're expecting the output to be given your example.

Try BeautifulSoup. Difficult to test this with your example though, as you have no nodes with a num >0, so this returns no venue names. You would need to provide an example of where you would get an output.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''<div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-row chooseTime" data-v-012d0593="">
    <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-col el-col-5 el-col-xs-0">
        <img data-v-174fb000="" data-v-3122d63c=""
            src="https://lcsd-smartplay.oss-cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/pic/default_facility.jpeg" alt="smartplay"
            class="venuen-img">
    </div>
    <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-col el-col-9 el-col-xs-24">
        <h3 data-v-3122d63c="" class="venuen-name">foo</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-col el-col-10 el-col-xs-24">
        <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-row">
            <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="site el-col el-col-24">boo</div>
            <div data-v-3122d63c="" class="el-col el-col-24 el-col-xs-24" style="padding: 2px 0px;">
                <div data-v-752ea580="" data-v-3122d63c="" class="facilities-date-list-box">
                    <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" data-v-752ea580="">
                        <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" class="smart-play-mobile">

                        </div><!----><!----><!---->
                        <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" class="smart-play-mobile-tablet">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-hidden scroll-wrap-223-308">
                        <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-scroll scroll-223-308">
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">yyy</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">xxx</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">zzz</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">qqq</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-v-752ea580="" class="facilities-date-list-item">
                                <div data-v-752ea580="" class="relative item-num-box-disable">
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="time flex">qqq</div>
                                    <div data-v-752ea580="" class="num">0</div><!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" data-v-752ea580="">
                        <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" class="smart-play-mobile"></div><!----><!----><!---->
                        <div data-v-42c8b4a0="" class="smart-play-mobile-tablet"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Find all divs with class 'num' where there is a num attribute
num_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='num')

# Filter divs where the text content is greater than 0
filtered_divs = [div for div in num_divs if div.get_text().isdigit() and int(div.get_text()) > 0]


# of those > 0, use the data-v- attributes of those to fetch out venue-name
filtered_data_v_values = []
for each in filtered_divs:
    for attr in each.attrs:
        if re.match(r'data-v-', attr):
            filtered_data_v_values.append(attr)
            
for each in filtered_data_v_values:
    venue_name = soup.find(attrs={each: True}, class_='venuen-name').text
    print(venue_name)
    

